# jquery validate on submit

Tags: jquery, validation

Can someone help with this validation?

```
$("#frm").submit(function() {
  $('#mailtoperson').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {           
      $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please check OK and YES once the email is ready to send');
    }
  });

 if ($('#mailtoperson').size() > 0) {
    $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please complete the required field.');
    return false;
  }
})
```

Basically I have a '`#frm`' with a textarea '`#mailtoperson`' and `onsubmit` I want to validate if '`#mailtoperson`' is blank, and if it is I want a '`pls complete`' message and if has data then I want the '`pls check ok`' message to populate.

Edit:

This seems to work to trigger the blank field function:

```
$('#frm').submit(function()
{
    if( !$(this).val() ) {
          $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please complete');

}
```

And this works for a simple on submit message

```
$('#frm').submit(function() {
$('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please check OK and YES once the email is ready to send');
})
```

});

But they do not work together - ie please complete if blank, and if not blank 'please check ok'...

Comment: ID's have to be unique, why do you have a each loop in `#mailtoperson` if there is only one element with that ID? Can you post your html also?

Comment: Best recomended jQuery form plugin -> http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ <- with it you can do things like `...beforeSubmit: function() { if (txt == "") return false; } ...` and the form wont submit. I love it! I use it for ALL my HTML forms!

Comment: Only one ID with #mailtoperson - loop not required I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#frm").submit(function() {
    if($('#mailtoperson').val().length == 0 ) {
        $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please complete...');
    } else {
        $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','pls check ok...');
    }
});
```

Comment: How does this include the onsubmit function?

Comment: aww, I have just escaped the onSubmit wrapper function dude and have just shown the validation part. you can wrap this up in your submit function call.

Comment: Sweet. Worked.  I had tried to add the submit function but I guess I had done it wrong.

Comment: @user2683780 : awesome :) Mind accepting the answer and an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

Use an if/else statement, also there's no need for a loop since there should only be one element with that id:

```
$("#frm").submit(function() {
  if($('#mailtoperson').val().trim() == '') {           
      $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please check OK and YES once the email is ready to send');
  }else{
      $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage','Please complete the required field.');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: No luck on this one either.  Form would not submit.

Comment: @user2683780 remove the `return false` or add it only inside the else

Comment: @user2683780 I don't know what smartWizard does, so I assumed you needed to prevent the default submit action so the messages were displayed that's why I added `return false;`